# Spring-WS service call from Android with ksoap.jar

Tags: android

I have developed a Spring-ws webservice using castor marshalling.  It is working fine with Axis2 client, but when I call the same service using Android client I get the following exception:

Please tell me what changes need to be done for the Android client.

```
"SoapFault - faultcode: 'SOAP-ENV:Server' faultstring:
'Castor unmarshalling exception; nested exception is org.exolab.castor.xml.MarshalException: 
The namespace associated with the prefix 'c' could not be resolved.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null"
```